# The meanings of these kinds of sentences such as “It has been three years.” “I have been married.”

Tags: present-perfect

I am learning the present perfect tense, and confusing a lot.
Here are three sentences.

- a. It has been three years.
- b. I have been married.
- c. He has learnt a lot.

What do they mean exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the tens­es and as­pects in English cor­re­spond tem­po­ral­ly to one an­oth­er?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tens-es-and-as-pects-in-english-cor-re-spond-tem-po-ral-ly-to-one-an)

Answer (score 1):

Sentences A and B are examples of using the Present Perfect Tense for a 'noncompleted past experience', for example: It's been 3 years or: l've been married / since l graduated from the university.
Sentence C is an example of using the Present Perfect Tense for an 'indefinite past experience with the present result', for example: l've learned a lot, so I can ask the boss for my promotion.